# Is it possible now (late 2023) to create a paid Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I saw information on the Internet that this was suspended in 2020, but there they were talking about the official API for creating paid subscriptions in the extension, and it seems like how else can you use the unofficial API for this. Another question is whether moderators will let such an extension pass? I also still see extensions in which you can subscribe (various VPNs), but it is possible that this is due to the fact that they did monetization before the restrictions were introduced, and they do not apply to those who did it before.